# MATLAB pixel values in gray scale images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Say, I have an RGB image `rgb` and a list of spatial coordinates `coords`. I would like to extract pixel values at spatial coordinates, for example, `[x1 y1]`, `[x2 y2]`, and `[x3 y3]`. For RGB images I can do so using:

```
rgb = imread('sample.jpg')
coords = [x1 y1; x2 y2; x3 y3];
pixelData = impixel(rgb, coords(:,1), coords(:,2));
```

Which returns red, green, and blue color values of specified image pixels.

`impixel` only works for color (RGB) images. But I want to extract the pixel values from a grayscale image `I`. I can do so using a `for` loop as follows

```
for i = 1:size(coords,1)
    pixelData(i,:) = I(coords(i,2), coords(i,1));
end
```

I would like to avoid using `for` loops. Is there another way to accomplish this?

`imstats = regionprops(mask, I,'PixelValues');` also works, but I would need an image `mask` first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html).

```
pixelData = I(sub2ind(size(I), coords(:,2), coords(:,1)));
```

Answer (score -3):

```
void Image::createImage(int width_x, int height_y)
{
   pixelData = new Color* [width];  // array of Pixel*

   for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
   {
       pixelData[x] = new Color [height];  // this is 2nd dimension of pixelData    
   }
}
```